# System.registerDynamic is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm

I upgraded jspm to 0.16.x. Normally, in dev mode it works fine. But whenever I do a `jspm bundle` and include that bundle file for production, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: System.registerDynamic is not a function`

Need help understanding and solving it.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Do a `jspm install` again to refresh the `jspm_packages/system.js` file.

Turns out I upgraded `jspm` but never re-installed `jspm_packages` again. The `system.js` file comes from `jspm_package/system.js`. Which means, until I re-did a `jspm install`, that file corresponded to an older version of `system.js`.